# Google Fusion - Won't Allow Me to Publish a Feature Map

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Here is the link to my public fusion table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1dp1DTZKzXWLE4TbI2Z9q-5jetC0iVt6ee_0eZdU8#map:id=3

I'm trying to publish the feature map and embed on a website, however 'Publish' is grayed out. Since I've set everything to public, I can't figure out what's preventing me from publishing and embedding.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested a workaround when you [asked this question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-fusion-tables/IPPIoKuz8Y0/MIlRpgoBAQAJ) on the product forum.

> I don't understand why it's happening, but there's something stuck in a strange state for this table. Can you try downloading it to a CSV file and reimporting to a new table? You'll have to redo your map styles, but publishing should work on a new version,